C# Hiding Progress Bar does not show last Step
With this code, the progress bar never shows 100%.
It only shows 75%. Is there any way to fix this?
Thanks!
Without the visible = false,
It shows 100%...
Note, that I have a timer firing off many events...
This is my code:
    progressBar.Minimum = 0;
    progressBar.Maximum = 100;

    public void Refresh()
    {
        progressBar.Step = 25;
        progressBar.PerformStep();

        progressBar.Step = 25;
        progressBar.PerformStep();

        progressBar.Step = 25;
        progressBar.PerformStep();

        progressBar.Step = 25;
        progressBar.PerformStep();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        progressBar.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Refresh();
    }


Thanks for the comment, your comment worked LarsTech!
progressBar.Minimum = 0;
progressBar.Maximum = 100;

public async void Refresh()
{
    progressBar.Step = 25;
    progressBar.PerformStep();

    progressBar.Step = 25;
    progressBar.PerformStep();

    progressBar.Step = 25;
    progressBar.PerformStep();

    progressBar.Step = 25;
    progressBar.PerformStep();

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    progressBar.Visible = false;
}

private void btnRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Refresh();
}


You should never declare a method async void unless it's an event handler. A method that would otherwise be declared with a return type of void, e.g. your Refresh method, should be declared async Task. Similarly, a method with a return type of SomeType becomes async Task<SomeType>.

Also, assuming that you've taken the above advice, you should await the Refresh method when you call it, i.e. await Refresh(). That would require your event handler to be async as well, so it should be declared async void.
